# Wordpress: problem in loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I have the following code:

```
    <?php
    query_posts("order=ASC&cat=4");
?>              
<?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <?php if(get_post_custom_values("show") != NULL): ?>
    <?php
        $categories = get_cat_ID(get_the_title());
        $url = get_category_link($categories);
    ?>
    <li class="thumb">
        <a href=""><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(215,200)); ?></a>
        <h2><a href=""><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>   
</ul>
```

This code works, but when you have `& -` in your title `$categories = get_cat_ID(get_the_title());` .. `get_cat_ID` won't work, do you know a work around?

Comment: One thing I can see right off the bat is that you don't need the `if(have_posts())` there...

Comment: Nop, doesn't do anything, I put it just for extra saftey :D

Answer (score 1):

Try [`get_category_by_slug`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) instead. Fetching the ID by the name of the category will get messy, especially with duplicates and characters, as you've discovered.

Comment: Doesn't it doesn't return the id for the first item, `$categories = get_category_by_slug(get_the_title());`

Comment: Do you know another method? :-s

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Get the ID of a specific category? The ID of the post's category (or categories)?

Comment: I'm trying to list a bunch of posts(products) from a category, and each post has a category, let's say if I have a post with the name of "Darling" that post is posted in a category called "darling" and I'm trying to list those posts, but link them with the link of the catory which is posted in, I hope you get what I said :( 'cause I need to get this working, It works but doesn't work for the posts with `- & ` in it you can see an example here: http://is.gd/6hBgbd ,  It works for the Section `Vitrinen` but the links won't work for Braut if you click on the images you will see

Comment: For `Vitrinen` I duplicated the same code, and It works, because of the titles

Comment: `$categories = get_category_by('slug',$wp_query->query_vars['term'],$wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy'])->name;`